# CSS Sprite Generator: I have the bundled image

Tags: css, code-generation, css-sprites

I have an image which I want to use as a sprite. Let's say the image has r x c rectangles of the same size which are to be used as backgrounds. Given the dimensions in the following image, how could we generate css for containers with classes <kbd>R1C1</kbd> through to <kbd>RnCm</kbd>? The symbols used are defined below the image.
[image: css sprite grid]

**OH** = Outer Height, **OW** = Outer Width,
**IH** = Inner Height, **IW** = Inner Width,
**VG** = Vertical Gutter, **HG** = Horizontal Gutter

P.S. I am not sure if I have used VG and HG correctly or they should be swapped in the image, please ignore this if the latter is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tutorial](http://cssglobe.com/post/3028/creating-easy-and-useful-css-sprites), which explains the technique in very simple terms and in a step-by-step manner. I will use it and build a tool. Then I'd share it here.

P.S. I would still accept an answer if it provides concrete help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a [CSS sprite generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/). I haven't tried this one myself but it should accept any ammount of images and output the right sprite and CSS code.

Comment: @Naosie: I know conventional generators (including the one you suggest), but these could not be used for this purpose. I do *not* have multiple images, I just have one (the combined image).

Comment: you could reverse-engineer it (I just wanted to use that word) and [slice](http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/photoshop/tool/slice.html) the sprite with Photoshop and re-make it with the sprite generator.

Comment: Yes, I am doing something similar, but not to get a single working sprite; I'm doing this to understand how the technique works (css-wize) so then I make a tool to automate similar jobs.

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't dynamic, so unless you're opposed to hand-writing each rule or using a tool like Dreamweaver ... you may want to consider using a dynamic CSS framework language like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to help generate your initial styles.